# NGINX Connection Too Slow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

When I try to download files that are on my server the speed is very slow. Static files like .css .js take a long time to load. How can I test to see if the problem is the server connection or the NGINX settings?

The current settings are:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 4096;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    ##
    # EasyEngine Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    server_tokens off;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    add_header X-Powered-By "New 1.0";
    add_header rt-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    # Limit Request
    limit_req_status 403;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;

    # Proxy Settings
    # set_real_ip_from  proxy-server-ip;
    # real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers CODE;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # Log format Settings
    log_format rt_cache '$remote_addr $upstream_response_time $upstream_cache_status [$time_local] '
    '$http_host "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types
        application/atom+xml
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/x-component
        text/xml
        text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determinate if is the network speed or the configuration of nginx server you could try to do a couple of thing:

load an image on the website (some image quite heavy, at last 200MB)

- serve it via a web page in nginx and whit developments tools of chrome/chromium open on the network tab and see how many time need to download it.
- download the same image via scp

Once you get both result you can compare theme and see, if they are very close to each other, that means is not related with nginx configuration, but could be the access to disk speed or connection.

to check the speed access to the disk try out with hdparm:

```
sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda
```

for test connetion speed you can try out with iperf a complete guide available here: https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/diagnostics/install-iperf-to-diagnose-network-speed-in-linux/